# typescript spreading object automatically intersect the type

Tags: typescript

```
type a = { a: string }
type b = { b: string }
type c = { c: string }


const A: a = { a: "123" }
const C: c = { c: "789" }
const B: b = { b: "456", a: "123" }// ok, error as expected
const B2: b = { b: "456", a: "123", ...C } // ok, error as expected
const B3: b = { b: "456", a: "123", ...A } // what, why no error as if it is B3:a&b
const B4: b = { b: "456", a: "123", w:"2020", ...A } // only w:"2020" error
```

questions1: why is B3 doesn't throw any error?

question2: how to solve this, how can I make B3 error?

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=11&ssc=54&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAhlC8UDesBcUDOwBOBLAdgOZQC%20AsAFCiRQBGCyd6WeRpl10Axgyl8zgLFyFSpS4B7fFigBBdHEQoY6AEQBGAEwBmVewqTpwKAGF0PJVH5RVAdgAcATj0jDMgELp6l2moAsAKwAbKoANGg2WrqkAPQxUBIA1uEQ2NgS2LAYUBAAHpBcwBAAJuJSHppevEw2gSHhKpE6YVAAdO0mpFBxCck5aRlZOfkQhSVlRlDu2lU%20-sEtjRrN4e2tsl09AO4AFjDA4bsgUPgS-emZMNm4AGZQuMa42dOoMABktBMefrOMvrULBpqKItLaoVSaAAMUJaaw2JCgYlEyMoQA)

Comment: That's expected behaviour but I can't remember the reasoning. There was something about the spread operation which changed the types. I'll try to find more.

Comment: OK, can't find what I am thinking of. It *exists* but I can't seem to find the right search terms. Somebody who knows what's going on should show up, soon, I hope.

Comment: @AlekseyL. ...great, there are comments from me on that question liking to other questions I found. Apparently, I was more capable in the past than I am now.

Comment: @VLAZ I still can't find any proper docs on this besides this issue https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/19775